# For loops for array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

How would I group 5 numbers in an array into each line? I've tried this code below but it results in something I'm not expecting it to be.

```
    $arrayCount = count($result_data);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
        {
            echo ($result_data[$i]);

        }
        echo ("\n");
    }
```

Result:

239298246244268

239298246244268

239298246244268

239298246244268

This loop keep repeating the first 5 numbers in my array. How do I make it to loop for every 5 numbers instead in my whole array of numbers? Thank you!

Comment: Please show your array and the output you expect.

Answer (score 1):

use this $result_data[$x] 
try this

```
$arrayCount = count($result_data);
    for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)
    {
        if($x%5==0)
        {
              echo ("\n");

        }
        echo ($result_data[$x]);  
    }
```

Comment: This would repeat the same character 5 times.

Comment: it not possible..have you checked this ? I am using $x not $i. echo statement is changed in my case ...

Comment: Yes, but $x is not changing in the $i loop.

Answer (score 1):

$x should be your index for the echo. Try this instead:

```
<?php

$result_data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

for ($x = 0; $x < count($result_data); $x++)
{
    echo ($result_data[$x]);
    if(($x+1)%5==0)
    {
        echo ("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about your `$result_data` Array, but probably it should go like this:

```
$arrayCount = count($result_data);
for ($x = 0; $x < $arrayCount; $x++)
{
    for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
    {
        echo ($result_data[$x][$i]);

    }
    echo ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this

```
$i = 0;
foreach($result_data as $result) {
  echo $result;
  if($i < 5) {
    echo ",";
  } else {
    echo "<br/>\n";
    $i = 0;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$chunks = array_chunk($result_data, 5);

foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
    echo implode('', $chunk);
    echo "\n";
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this several line code:

```
$valuesDelimiter = ', ';
$lineDelimiter   = "\n";
$input_array     = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
$slited_array    = array_chunk($input_array, 5);
array_walk($slited_array, function(&$arr) {$arr = implode($valuesDelimiter, $arr);});
$result = implode($lineDelimiter, $slited_array);
```